# Concrete example of Sweedlers notation

Tags: category-theory, notation, hopf-algebras

I am working on a relatively easy example with the graphical calculus. I am very familiar with this while I am still very uncomfortable with Sweedlers notation and translating graphs into algebraic formulas. But let me present my example:

I have a finite dimensional Hopf algebra $H$, an $H$-comodule C with coaction $\delta: C \rightarrow C \otimes H$, an $H$-module M with action $\rho: H \otimes M \rightarrow M$, and an vector space $V$ which is not important at this time.

Then I want to show that the following map is an isomorphism:

[image]

I will argue that this map here is the inverse:

[image]

This happens in one direction (the other is similar) like this:

[image]

Where I used the well-known fact that to act two times is the same as act with the multiplication (same for coaction). In the second step I used the following property of the antipode:

[image]

So far, so good. Now I don't want to give graphs but formulas. I expect this to be relatively easy formulas as the graphs aren't complicated either.

My first step was to define the maps:

The first one is given by $$(\rho \otimes \mathrm{id}_{V \otimes C}) \circ ASS \circ ( \mathrm{id}_{M \otimes V} \otimes \delta)$$

and the second one is given by:

$$(\rho \otimes \mathrm{id}_{V \otimes C}) \circ ASS \circ (\mathrm{id}_{M \otimes V \otimes C} \otimes S) \circ ( \mathrm{id}_{M \otimes V} \otimes \delta)$$

in both ASS is just the associator for switching things around, I guess we can just leave those, because they are isomorphisms anyway.

Now I get confused:

\begin{align}
(\rho \otimes \mathrm{id}_{V \otimes C}) \circ ASS \circ ( \mathrm{id}_{M \otimes V} &\otimes \delta)(m \otimes v \otimes c) \\
&=(\rho \otimes \mathrm{id}_{V \otimes C}) \circ ASS(m \otimes v \otimes c_{(0)} \otimes c_{(-1)}) \\
&=(\rho \otimes \mathrm{id}_{V \otimes C})(c_{(-1)} \otimes m \otimes v \otimes c_{(0)}) \\
&= m_{(0)} \otimes v \otimes c_{(0)}
\end{align}

Now the second equation: 
\begin{align}
(\rho \otimes \mathrm{id}_{V \otimes C}) \circ ASS \circ (\mathrm{id}_{M \otimes V \otimes C} &\otimes S) \circ ( \mathrm{id}_{M \otimes V} \otimes \delta)(m_{(0)} \otimes v \otimes c_{(0)}) \\
&=(\rho \otimes \mathrm{id}_{V \otimes C}) \circ ASS \circ (\mathrm{id}_{M \otimes V \otimes C} \otimes S)(m_{0} \otimes v \otimes c_{(0)(0)} \otimes c_{(-1)}) \\
&=(\rho \otimes \mathrm{id}_{V \otimes C}) \circ ASS (m_{0} \otimes v \otimes c_{(0)(0)} \otimes S(c_{(-1)}) \\
&= (\rho \otimes \mathrm{id}_{V \otimes C})(S(c_{(-1)}) \otimes m_{0} \otimes v \otimes c_{(0)(0)})
\end{align}

yeah but well, in this last line I have no chance to continue or to use any rule. Can anybody help me fix this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Don't leave blank lines.  In TeX it signifies a new paragraph so breaks out of align*, hence align* isn't closed properly with an `\end{align*}` and MathJax stop attempting to generate the result.

Comment: My advice is that you should write every fórmula with the corresponding picture (in a sepaeate paper with you). Every picture means a fórmula, so, if you have a pictóricas proof, you should be able to translate it. Usually a concatenation of pictures is very easy to understand, but a concatenation of 2 formulas is a mess.. so, without going step by step, usually you don't go very far with formulae..